# curl download: waiting on task and then downloading, all in one command

Tags: curl, download

The [DepMap database](https://depmap.org/portal/) facilitates [downloads of "custom" data](https://depmap.org/portal/download/custom/) like "Expression Public 23Q4" with a task system:

1. First `curl`: gives a task ID
2. Second `curl` using the task ID: gives a progress percentage
3. Eventually, when "state" is "SUCCESS" it gives a download URL
4. Last `curl` on the download URL: downloads the desired file

Here is the first command:

```bash
curl https://depmap.org/portal/api/download/custom -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{"datasetId":"expression","dropEmpty":true,"addCellLineMetadata":false}'
```

Is there some `curl` trick that can automate this process into one `curl` command?

Comment: Why does it have to be 1 command? Write a shell script.

Comment: It can be a shell script yes, that's what I currently have. I was hoping to migrate away from a script to one command, if it's supported

Comment: why? I don't think curl has it's own scripting.